# Get intersection from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, mapping, tuples

I have two list of tuples

```
a = [('head1','a'),('head2','b'),('head3','x'),('head4','z')]
b = [('head5','u'),('head6','w'),('head7','x'),('head8','y'),('head9','z')]
```

I want to take the intersection of 2nd element of each tuple for example set `{a[0][0],a[0][1],a[0][2],a[0][3]}` intersection with set `{b[0][0],b[0][1],b[0][2],b[0][3],b[0][4]}` from list `a` and `b` such that it returns the first element mapping of the tuple if intersection value exist. The resulting output should be like following:

```
res = [('head3','head7'),('head4','head9')]
```

So far I have tried this:

```
x = [(a[i][0],b[j][0]) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(b)) if a[0][i] == b[0][j]]
```

but got an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

What could be the correct and fastest way of doing this ?

Comment: "I want to take the intersection of 2nd element of each tuple" Your example does not indicate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following in Python 3. Create dicts from your lists, taking the intersection of keys from both dicts, fetch the corresponding values at the key:

```
>>> da = {k:v for v, k in a}
>>> db = {k:v for v, k in b}
>>> [(da[k], db[k])  for k in da.keys()&db.keys()]
[('head4', 'head9'), ('head3', 'head7')]
```

In Python 2, you can use `set(da).intersection(db)` in place of `da.keys()&db.keys()`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a function with a generator:

```
def pairs():
   a = [('head1','a'),('head2','b'),('head3','x'),('head4','z')]
   b = [('head5','u'),('head6','w'),('head7','x'),('head8','y'),('head9','z')]

   for val1, val2 in a:
       for val3, val4 in b:
           if val2 == val4:
               yield (val1, val3)

print(list(pairs()))
```

Output:

```
[('head3', 'head7'), ('head4', 'head9')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a list comprehension like this

```
a = [('head1','a'),('head2','b'),('head3','x'),('head4','z')]
b = [('head5','u'),('head6','w'),('head7','x'),('head8','y'),('head9','z')]

pairs = [(val1,val3) for val1,val2 in a for val3,val4 in b if val2 == val4]
print(pairs)
```